# Angularjs select with ng-repeat, on select bind ng-model with object

Tags: javascript, angularjs

After my get request i get

```
$scope.variables = response.data;
```

my select is:

```
<select name="varSelect" id="varSelect" ng-model="wid.adapter">
            <option ng-repeat="variable in variables" value="{{variable.id}}">{{variable.name}}</option>
</select>
```

after that i have two input text fields

```
<input type="text" ng-model="wid.url" />
<input type="text" ng-model="wid.name" />
```

On button click i want to post wid

```
$http.post(some_url, $scope.wid).then(function (response) {
            console.log(response);
});
```

My problem is that i dont get the object variable in wid.adapter. I gog the id.
How to modify my code to get the variable instead of id?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use the `variable` as the value not the `id`

and use the `ng-option` attribute on the select to bind it properly

```
<select name="varSelect" id="varSelect" ng-model="wid.adapter"
    ng-options="variable.name for variable in variables">
    </select>
```

Comment: when i use variable instead of id i got json string.

Comment: the second part is working, with ng option. tnx a lot

Comment: the second one uses angular binding instead of typical html behavior

Comment: @M B how can I set placeholder at position one. First time input select is empty. I want to put some value in select.

Comment: @VSH set the `ng-model` to the value you want to select